# Is there a similar mechanism to Python's threading.Event in OpenMP?

Tags: python, c, openmp

I'm trying to make a list of solutions to implement the functionality of Python's `threading.Event` [1] in C.

Normally, when synchronization between threads is needed, the first mechanism to be used/explained is a Lock (aka mutex). The python's `threading.Event` class, is another mechanism for synchronization that can be used to atomically block threads until a particular condition is true.

With `pthread` I think this is possible to do this with condition variable attributes [2].

What about `omp`, is this possible? Based on what happens in python, I have written the following example with the **fictional** types `Event` and `EventsQueue`:

```
int nthreads;
Event *evt;
EventsQueue *queue;

#pragma omp parallel private(evt)
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads()-1;
    }
    if (!omp_get_thread_num()) /*master thread*/
    {
        while (nthreads)
        {
            evt = events_queue_pop(queue);
            evt_set(evt);
        }
    }
    else                       /*other threads */
    {
        evt = alloc_event();
        events_queue_append(queue, evt);
        /* each threads waits for master thread to set its event*/
        evt_wait(evt);
        free_event(evt);
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            nthreads--;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I can get a similar effect of Python's `threading.Lock` with `#pragma omp critical` (in the example I protect `nthreads` with it). The problem is `threading.Event`. I cant find anything like it for OpenMP.

[1] http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects

[2] http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node31.html#SECTION003120000000000000000

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think OpenMP has any concept like events; you could certainly use locks (`omp_lock_t`) and explicitly spin-wait on them until they are unset, if that was good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: This solution is not correct. Look at the EDIT in the end of this answer.

Well... I think I've found how to do it. Looking at the source of Python's threading module, [1], it actually seems simple.

Its a matter of keeping a *FIFO* of *reentrant locks* (which in OpenMP is implemented as `omp_nest_lock_t`). Whenever a `Event.wait([timeout])` is called, a new lock is appended to the *FIFO* and immediately *acquired* two times (the second time will block until the first is released!).
Then, when `Event.set()` is called, all the locks in the *FIFO* are released and removed from it.

I hope this answer can be of some use to anyone who has this problem in the future.

[1] http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/py3k/Lib/threading.py

EDIT: I've found an article that says that this solution is not correct and talks about this problem:

[2] http://www.michaelsuess.net/publications/wirz_suess_leopold_taskpools_06.pdf